# How to traverse list of nested maps in scala

Tags: json, scala, hashmap

I have been given a json string that looks like the following one:

```
{
  "dataflows": [
    {
  "name": "test",
  "sources": [
    {
      "name": "person_inputs",
      "path": "/data/input/events/person/*",
      "format": "JSON"
    }
  ],
  "transformations": [
    {
      "name": "validation",
      "type": "validate_fields",
      "params": {
        "input": "person_inputs",
        "validations": [
          {
            "field": "office",
            "validations": [
              "notEmpty"
            ]
          },
          {
            "field": "age",
            "validations": [
              "notNull"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ok_with_date",
      "type": "add_fields",
      "params": {
        "input": "validation_ok",
        "addFields": [
          {
            "name": "dt",
            "function": "current_timestamp"


          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sinks": [
    {
      "input": "ok_with_date",
      "name": "raw-ok",
      "paths": [
        "/data/output/events/person"
      ],
      "format": "JSON",
      "saveMode": "OVERWRITE"
    },
    {
      "input": "validation_ko",
      "name": "raw-ko",
      "paths": [
        "/data/output/discards/person"
      ],
      "format": "JSON",
      "saveMode": "OVERWRITE"
    }
```

And I have been asked to use it as some kind of recipe for an ETL pipeline, i.e., the data must be extracted from the "path" specifid in the "sources" key, the transformations to be carried out are specified within the "transformations" key and, finally, the transformed data must saved to one of the two specified "sink" keys.

I have decided to convert the json string into a scala map, as follows:

```
val json = Source.fromFile("path/to/json")
//parse
val parsedJson = jsonStrToMap(json.mkString)
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
val parsedJson = parse(jsonStr).extract[Map[String, Any]]
```

so, with that, I get a structure like this one:

[image]

which is a map whose first value is a list of maps. I can evaluate `parsedJson("dataflows")` to get:

[image]

which is a list, as expected, but, then I cannot traverse such list, even though I need to in order to get to the sources, transformations and sinks. I have tried using the index of the listto, for example, get its first element, like this: `parsedJson("dataflows")(0)`, but to no avail.

Can anyone please help me traverse this structure? Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to convert the JSON to the full data structure that you have been provided rather than just `Map[String, Any]`. This makes it trivial to pick out the data that you want. For example,

```
val dataFlows = parse(jsonStr).extract[DataFlows]

case class DataFlows(dataflows: List[DataFlow])
case class DataFlow(name: String, sources: List[Source], transformations: List[Transformation], sinks: List[Sink])
case class Source(name: String, path: String, format: String)
case class Transformation(name: String, `type`: String, params: List[Param])
case class Param(input: String, validations: List[Validation])
case class Validation(field: String, validations: List[String])
case class Sink(input: String, name: String, paths: List[String], format: String, saveMode: String)
```

The idea is to make the JSON handler do most of the work to create a type-safe version of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate `parsedJson("dataflows")` a `Tuple2` is returned aka a `Tuple` which has two elements that are accessed with `._1` and `._2`

So for `dataflows(1)._1` the value returned is "sources" and `dataflows(1)._2` is list of maps (List[Map[K,V]) which can be traversed like you would normally traverse elements of a `List` where each element is `Map`

Let's deconstruct this for example:

`val dataFlowsZero = ("sources", List(Map(42 -> "foo"), Map(42 -> "bar")))`

The first element in the `Tuple`

```
scala> dataFlowsZero._1
String = sources
```

The second element in the `Tuple`

```
scala> dataFlowsZero._2
List[Map[Int, String]] = List(Map(42 -> foo), Map(42 -> bar))`
```

Map the keys in each `Map` in `List` to a new `List`

```
scala> dataFlowsZero._2.map(m => m.keys)                                                                                                                                                                    
List[Iterable[Int]] = List(Set(42), Set(42))
```

Map the values in each `Map` in the `List` to a new `List`

```
scala> dataFlowsZero._2.map(m => m.values)
List[Iterable[String]] = List(Iterable(foo), Iterable(bar))
```